# Update CSRF form input input using javascript

Tags: django, forms, angularjs, csrf, django-csrf

I have multiple forms on a page, all using the CSRF token template tag {% csrf_token %} Im using Angular $http to post the forms.

All the forms have the same CSRF token so when i post one form it invalidates the others.

Is there a way that when i post a form, I get a new CSRF token from the server which i can use to update the forms.

I tried getting the new CSRF token from the response header using $http headers() but it is not available.

Comment: The CSRF middleware does not invalidate tokens upon use. The CSRF token only changes upon a new login; it remains the same as long as the same user is logged in. Your problem is not caused by CSRF tokens being invalidated, unless the form you post actually performs a login.

Comment: A bit more detail, I have a registratio and login form on the same page, both have a token say CZQOkC6LUEOixqFYzDiZYlTyY89KoFII . I can register as a user fine however if i try login on the same page (without refresh) i get a 403 forbidden "CSRF token missing or incorrect" ?

Answer (score 2):

The browser cookie holding the CSRF token should be updated after your login request. You should be able to get the new token from the `csrftoken` cookie, as demonstrated in the [CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax):

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

You should also be able to skip most of this boilerplate and just use [the AngularJS $cookies API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookies):

```
var csrftoken = $cookie.csrftoken;
```

Comment: +1 for the angular cookie suggestion however, although the csrftoken is in the request I'm not seeing it in $cookies (I'm seeing all other cookies) any suggestions

Comment: Can you check if you see the `csrftoken` in the raw `document.cookie` string? Angular might be feeding you stale data, but the browser cookie storage should have been updated with the new CSRF token received with your AJAX response.

Comment: csrf is also missing from document.cookie i should have mentioned this :( Any ideas on how i can get the new csrf token (received from AJAX response). I tried $headers but no luck

Comment: At the point your view is called, the CSRF token should be already regenerated. You should be able to access the _new_ token within your view as `request.csrf_token`. You can arrange to pass it explicitly with the response somehow.

Comment: This is what i ended up doing, bit of a hack. I explicitly set the CSRF token on the response and used $header() to get it and update the Angular post header

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack but this is what i ended up doing:

In my response i explicitly set the new CSRF token value

```
response['new_csrf'] = self.request.META['CSRF_COOKIE']
return response
```

This can then be accessed on the client using Angular $headers()

```
var new_csrf = headers()['new_csrf']
```

I then update the $hhtp post header

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = new_csrf;
```